How can I speed up copying filtered cells to new workbook?
I have code to copy filtered cells to a new workbook. It takes almost two minutes to run. How can I adjust the code so it runs faster?
The filtered data is part of a worksheet with over 10 000 lines, and each week this increases by approximately 1500 lines. (Each year a new file is created, but at the end of the year it's a rather long sheet.)
Sub FilterRows()

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Calculation = xlManual
  End With
  
  Dim NewBook As Workbook
  Dim Rng As Range
  
  Dim myDate As Date: myDate = Application.Max(Columns(1))
  
  Dim DataStock As Worksheet
  Set DataStock = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Stock")
   
  With DataStock.Range("A1")
  
    'Check last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
   
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
  
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Format(myDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>DSS GNT", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>DSS BUGGENHOUT"
          
    .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="1"
    
    .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Array("SNE", "BUG", "GEN", "EUR", "HAM", "MKG", "RHE", "RTZ", "STO"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="Y"
    
    lastRow = DataStock.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Stock").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.Copy NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
  
  End With
          
  With Application
    .CutCopyMode    = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts  = True
    .Calculation    = xlAutomatic
  End With
  
End Sub


Don't you know the range (non filtered) which is going to be filtered? You should set Rng as SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), then iterate between each Area of Rng and put each row in an array (preliminarily ReDim for maximum number of rows `rng1 has and its columns (which you must know). Finally drop the array content, at once. It will be 100 times faster.

Can you supply the range to be processed in terms of involved columns ("A:W", for instance) and on which row is the header? Is it the first row? Supposing that all columns ends to the same row would it be correct?

What does Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, ... mean? What selection to be taken in consideration? Is DataStock the active sheet? If so, why using two ways of refer it? If not, you may have surprises using this way of sheet qualifying.

You did not answer any of my above clarification questions and not answering related to my suggestions, which is not so convenient when expected for help...
Anyhow, please try the next way which should be must faster. It assumes that the headers are on the first row of the sheet to be processed:
Sub FilterRows()
    Dim NewBook As Workbook, DataStock As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim colsNo As Long, iRows As Long, arr

    Set DataStock = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Stock")
    Dim myDate As Date: myDate = Application.Max(DataStock.Columns(1))
    
    DataStock.AutoFilterMode = False
    Set rng = DataStock.UsedRange 'the range to be filtered
    colsNo = rng.Columns.count    'it returns the number of columns to be places in the final array
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'some optimization
    With rng 'I assumed that the headers are on the first row...

      .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & myDate
      .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<>DSS GNT", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>DSS BUGGENHOUT"
          
      .AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="1"
    
      .AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:=Array("SNE", "BUG", "GEN", "EUR", "HAM", "MKG", "RHE", "RTZ", "STO"), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
      .AutoFilter field:=20, Criteria1:="Y"
      
      iRows = rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).cells.count ' determining the filtered array number of rows
      Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)                         'extracting visible cells of the filtered range
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Place the discontinuous range in a 2D continuous array:
    arr = Extract2DArray(rng, iRows, colsNo) ' adding the fourth parameters as `True it will skip headers row

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'add a single-sheet workbook
    
    'drop the array content in the first sheet of the newly added workbook, at once:
    NewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

    MsgBox "Job Done..."
End Sub

'no headers Optional variable allows returning with headers or without. Using the fours argument as True, headers are skipped
Function Extract2DArray(rg As Range, rNo As Long, cNo As Long, Optional noHeaders As Boolean = False) As Variant
  Dim arrRet, j As Long, iRow As Range, k As Long, A As Range
  
  ReDim arrRet(1 To rNo - IIf(noHeaders, 1, 0), 1 To cNo) 'ReDim the necessary array
   For Each A In rg.Areas     'iterate between all range areas
     For Each iRow In A.rows  'iterate between all area rows
        If noHeaders And k = 0 Then GoTo SkipHeadersRow 'skip the first row, if no headers wanted
        k = k + 1
        For j = 1 To cNo
           arrRet(k, j) = iRow.cells(1, j) 'fill the array fow by columns
        Next j
SkipHeadersRow: noHeaders = False
     Next iRow
   Next A
   Extract2DArray = arrRet
End Function

Your code had some bad issues. Firstly, it created a filter for all existing columns in a sheet (16384) consuming Excel resources for filtering itself and for tranformming a discontinuous range in a continuous one to be pasted. Then, it used a set Worksheet, against the active one. If the active sheet was not the set one, it will raise errors or wrong filtering. A selection to be filtered also appeared, without selecting anything and so on.
Please, test the above suggested solution and send some feedback.

I must admit I don't know how to  adapt my code based on your first comment (I'm a novice at VBA) . The header is on row 1, and the range of columns is B:R, all columns end on same row. The 'Selection.AutoFilter field:=3,' is to filter out two values. Datastock is the active sheet.

I tested your code, but I run into error : AutoFilter method of Range class failed (Error 1004) , it occurs at the first autofilter line. I can very well understand my code had some bad issues, I'm a novice at coding, it's mostly an assembly of adapted codes I found on Internet, including this forum.

@shaye You said that your code works, but it is slow... How could it run using  With DataStock.Range("A1") and first filter uses Field:=1? Do you understand what does Field:=1 mean? Then, how to work on columns "B:R" and using .AutoFilter field:=20, Criteria1:="Y"? Field means the column number of the range to be filtered!. For "B:R" range the maximum such column number is 17! Do you select some columns before running the code? If not something confidential, can you share the workbook you try working on?

@shaye If the range to be filtered in terms of columns is "B:R", as you said please, confirm that the filters MUST be applied on columns "B:B" (max date), "D:D" (to not be "<>DSS GNT" or "<>DSS BUGGENHOUT"), "N:N" (to be 1), "O:O" (the criteria array containing "SNE", "BUG", etc.)? And which column to contain "Y"? Field:=20 means column "U:U"...

@shaye Please, create  a simple testing macro, select the sheet where you try applying the filter and use the next code Debug.Print ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address. Then use Ctrl + G to openn Immediate Window. What does it return in Immediate Window?

@shaye Related to your first comment here, please let us know 1.) if column A is empty, 2.) which column has the dates (A or B), and 3.) if you would like to copy from B:R to A:Q or from A:R to A:R.

It appears the problem was in the columns after my UsedRange, I selected all rows after my last row, and deleted them, now the marco runs smoothly ! Thanks for the time you put in my request, much appreciated !

@shaye But the last filter using Field:=20 exceeds the filtered range number of columns... And the first (A:A column) must be completely empty, to make the used range starting from B:B...

I only need to copy the data from B:R for my new sheet, but there is a filter in column A and T aswell, so I should have said range 'A:T'

Efficiently Copy Filtered Data to a New Workbook
Source (Old)

Destination (New)

Main
Sub ExportRecentData()
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Data Stock"
    Const SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B1"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1" ' modify!
    Const DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const HEADER_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 1
    Const COPY_ALL_COLUMNS As Boolean = True
    Const DST_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 17 ' ignored if 'COPY_ALL_COLUMNS = True'
    ' Use a more meaningful variable name!
    Dim MyTypes() As Variant: MyTypes = Array( _
        "SNE", "BUG", "GEN", "EUR", "HAM", "MKG", "RHE", "RTZ", "STO")
    
    ' READ: Return the values from the source list ('srg')
    ' in a 2D one-based array ('Data').
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = RefCurrentRegion(sws.Range(SRC_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS))
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count ' source
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count ' both
    
    ' Determine the number of destintion columns.
    Dim dcCount As Long
    If COPY_ALL_COLUMNS Then
        dcCount = scCount
    Else
        dcCount = DST_COLUMNS_COUNT
        If dcCount > scCount Then
            MsgBox "Not enough columns!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Use a more meaningful variable name!
    Dim MyDate As Date: MyDate = Application.Max(srg.Columns(1))
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = HEADER_ROWS_COUNT ' skip headers

    ' MODIFY: Loop through the data rows of the array and return the values
    ' of each matching row at the top (below the headers) of the array.

    Dim sRow As Long

    For sRow = HEADER_ROWS_COUNT + 1 To srCount ' skip headers
        If DataRowMeetsCriteria(Data, sRow, MyDate, MyTypes) Then ' meets crit.
            dRow = dRow + 1
            MoveDataRow Data, sRow, dRow, dcCount ' move to top
        'Else ' doesn't meet criteria
        End If
    Next sRow

    If dRow = HEADER_ROWS_COUNT Then
        MsgBox "No filtered rows!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' WRITE: Copy the values from the top of the array to a new workbook.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Create references.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
    dws.Name = DST_SHEET_NAME ' rename
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(dRow, dcCount)

    ' Copy values.
    drg.Value = Data

    ' Copy formatting.
    srg.Resize(dRow, dcCount).Copy
    drg.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    drg.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.Goto dcell
    
    ' Just for easy closing while testing.
    dwb.Saved = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
        
    MsgBox "Recent data exported to a new workbook.", vbInformation
  
End Sub

Help
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      References the range from a given cell ('firstCell')
'               to the last cell of the given cell's current region.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCurrentRegion(firstCell As Range) As Range
    
    If firstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With firstCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = firstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - firstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - firstCell.Column)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a row
'               in a 2D one-based array meets all criteria.
' Remarks:      To increase efficiency, eliminate rows using
'               the simpler conditions first.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DataRowMeetsCriteria( _
    Data As Variant, _
    Row As Long, _
    MyDate As Date, _
    MyTypes As Variant) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim Value As Variant
    
    ' Col 'N'
    Value = CStr(Data(Row, 13))
    If Value <> "1" Then Exit Function
    ' Col 'U'
    Value = CStr(Data(Row, 20))
    If Value <> "Y" Then Exit Function
    ' Col 'D'
    Value = CStr(Data(Row, 3))
    If Value = "DSS GNT" Then Exit Function
    If Value = "DSS BUGGENHOUT" Then Exit Function
    ' Col 'B'
    Value = Data(Row, 1)
    If Not IsDate(Value) Then Exit Function
    If Value <> MyDate Then Exit Function
    ' Col 'O'
    Value = CStr(Data(Row, 14))
    If IsError(Application.Match(Value, MyTypes, 0)) Then Exit Function
    
    DataRowMeetsCriteria = True

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a 2D one-based array ('Data'), moves the values
'               from one row ('OldRow') to another ('NewRow') overwriting
'               the values of the former.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub MoveDataRow( _
        ByRef Data As Variant, _
        OldRow As Long, _
        NewRow As Long, _
        NewColumnsCount As Long)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To NewColumnsCount
        Data(NewRow, c) = Data(OldRow, c)
    Next c
End Sub

